# ArrayAppend returning boolean instead of array

Tags: data-structures, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

OK I have been struggling with this for sometime and I figured I would go back to the basics and try and figure out my error, as I get the same error here as I do down the line.

Here is my Code:

```
<cfparam name="session.cart" default="arrayNew(1)">
<cfset session.cart = arrayAppend(session.cart,structNew() )>

<cfset thisCartItem = arraylen(session.cart)>

<cfset session.cart[thisCartItem].itemID = "X">
<cfset session.cart[thisCartItem].quantity = "X">
<cfset session.cart[thisCartItem].itemName = "X">

<cfdump var="#session.cart#">
```

Here is my error:

> Object of type class java.lang.Boolean cannot be used as an array

Comment: The error means exactly what it says :) `session.cart` is not an array. `arrayAppend` returns a boolean value, *not* an array object.

Comment: How would I get about setting up the array other then the way I have?

Comment: See my answer below. Also, note the comments about using pound signs in the `cfparam`. Without them, the code does not create an array. It just sets that variable equal to the literal characters "arrayNew(1)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says. The variable `session.cart` is not an array. It is a boolean value. If you read the [ArrayAppend documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayappend.html) it explains why. The function modifies the array in place and returns a boolean value:

> **Returns** True, on successful completion.

By capturing the result here, you are actually setting the cart value to `true/false`:

```
<!--- Note the addition of the pound signs in the CFPARAM --->
<cfparam name="session.cart" default="#arrayNew(1)#">
<cfset session.cart = arrayAppend(session.cart, structNew())>
```

Having said that, you could simplify the code a lot by using the shorthand syntax supported in all recent versions of CF ie `{}` - new structure and `[]` - new array. To create a new array:

```
<cfset session.cart = []>
```

To append one or more structures to the end of that array:

```
<!--- append first structure to array --->
<cfset ArrayAppend( session.cart
                        , { itemID = "X", quantity = "X", itemName = "X" }
                  )>

<!--- append second structure to array --->
<cfset ArrayAppend( session.cart
                        , { itemID = "Y", quantity = "Y", itemName = "Y" }
                  )>
```

Comment: I haven't worked with shorthand at all and am fairly new to CF in general, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Another quick question would be how do I continue to add on to that array. If I run the command over it just changed the structure in the first array

Comment: Also do you happen to have a link that can teach me a little more about shorthand it seems a lot more condensed and probably a bit easier once I get the hang of it.

Comment: (Edit) *continue to add on to that array.* That is what ArrayAppend does. It adds whatever object you supply on to the *end* of the array.  The example above creates a new array for demo purposes only. Maybe you accidentally included that in your code? See this demo: http://trycf.com/gist/36bb30144cb35c6467a91dfa979775d9/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: I wanted to be able to add things one at a time if needed, I thought running the Append command again (add to cart button) would add another, but when I run it it just replaces the first one. Your other example works great and adds two different item but at one time I need to be able to add one by one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: *more about shorthand*  I do not remember the exact location off the top of my head, but it should be under "Using Arrays and Structures".  A quick search turned up these two links http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fb2.html and 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09f0b-7fd5.html

Comment: *it just replaces the first one* That should not happen unless maybe you are overwriting the array on each request OR if maybe the session scope is not initialized in your Application.cfc.

Comment: Its seem im overwriting each time. Hmm this has been bothering me for days lol. Thanks for the help, looks like I have a little more studying to get to get this figured out.

Comment: <cfapplication name="MyApp" clientmanagement="Yes" sessionmanagement="Yes" sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(2,0,0,0)#" applicationtimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,2,0,0)#"/>

Comment: I have got to run, but take a look at this starter example (two files): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d7e3def5481c0236514cb05348c2ba39 . Notice it never overwrites the array? It just appends a new item to the end each time you click submit.